# Getting timeout in front end after 30 seconds (Technology used -Scala, akka, nginx and react/node js)

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, timeout, akka

My application flow is:

```
nginx = > react app = > nginx => akka http
```

All other functionality working fine when execute within 30 sec.

we have created one new API to export patient details in csv file, this export request takes 2.5 min to execute. we are using below technology for this app: Scala, akka, nginx and react/node js as front end.

when I will hit on export link, request got executed and able to see in logs. but immediately after 30sec got error on browser console GET /export/request 503 (service unavailable ) with java script error in promise block.

If we have tried to access API directly from curl command (as we have been using to load patient data) then, we are able to export data from TEST site as well (1.8 min). there is no timeout or 503 issue at backend (akka http)

I have observed this issue will come for all API’s, if their execution takes more than 30 sec then we will get 503 error on console. We have tested observed this after adding 30sec wait statement [Thread.sleep(30sec)]

**Solution applied:**

1. after referring akka documentation I have increased ideal-timeout setting to 240s.

application.conf:

```
http {
    server {
      request-timeout: 240s
       idle-timeout: 240s
    }
  }
```

and it works on my local/development env. /export/ request was executed in 2 min.

after deploying this change at TEST env. issue is still there getting 503 after 30 sec. on TEST env. application is running with docker env.

request flow/application setup:

Internal AWS load balancer => EC2 instance => nginx proxy (listing :80) => front end app (react js app) => backend (scala and akka)

2. Upgraded nginx from 1.9 to 1.21
3. After details analysis, this issue is coming only if request goes form Front end proxy (Nginx- Docker image) : in nginx/default.conf Fine tune all time out parameters but still it’s not working.

   ```
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_read_timeout 100;
        proxy_connect_timeout 100;
        proxy_send_timeout 100;
    }
   ```
4. Increased time at load balancer from 60 sec to 700 sec.

All Above solutions are not working, still getting 503 error while downloading CSV.

Please help me.

Comment: You need to address the performance issue in your back-end, or restructure this setup to use an asynchronous messaging technology.  HTTP responses almost always take seconds, not minutes, to respond, and if a connection gets dropped a client is likely to retry the message.  (Speaking of...didn't I see this same question yesterday...but it didn't get an answer...so there was a retry?)